# The advantage cast pointer to void* when use new

Tags: c++, stl

`stl_construct.h` has the following function:

```
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
inline void
_Construct(_T1* __p, const _T2& __value)
{
   ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(__value);
}
```

I want to know why casting `__p` to `void*` is needed, is there any advantage?

Comment: Not sure, but it asserts `__p` is a pointer that can be used for the placement?

Comment: The danger of reading the internal library code that I've encountered is that the (new) programmer starts to *use* the internals in their own code (no I'm not joking -- I have seen this in some code).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It guarantees that the pre-defined placement new operator is called, rather than any overload added to the global namespace by user code with the signature `void* operator new(std::size_t, _T1*)`.

Answer (score 3):

It ensure a potentially _T1* cast operator does not get unitentionally executed

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of when this happens? This looks like a placement construction, so the pointer should have the same alignment as the buffer, usually `alignof(char*/void*)`.

Comment: In the case of Brian's answer, only it *finds* an overloaded `new` through implicit conversion, rather than one provided for that type.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sure that any `void* operator new(size_t, _T1*);` doesn't get in the way of the placement new it is trying to do.